# Asynchrounus updating array

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous

is it possible to update an java script array asyncronously?
It should look like this:

```
export const main = async () => {
    let array = []
    const update = async() => {
       //this should update the array every "interval"-seconds              
    }
    update();
    setInterval(update, interval);
    const usage = async() => {
       //this uses the array every n-seconds             
    }
    usage();
    setInterval(usage, n);
```

the update function calls an async function to fetch data and should replace the old data in the array the array always has the same size

Comment: You can update the array using setInterval. If you're not going to use any promises in `update()`, you don't need to set function to async.

Answer (score 0):

Adding async logic unnecessarily, can cause your functions to actually run [slower](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/async-await-is-not-about-making-asynchronous-code-synchronous-ba5937a0c11e). Therefore, its important to understand when you should use it.

For example, if you're doing a lot of work on an array (i.e looping over an array of +1000 items, etc) or fetching data from a server, async logic WILL make your code run faster, as the browser can ensure the task is non-blocking. If not, you're best bet is to keep it synchronous.

Note: Javascript cannot run scripts concurrently (at the same time). It is a single-threaded language. To do something that mimics concurrency on the browser, you can look into something called [Webworkers API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), that is provided by the browser. It allows you to run javascript in a concurrent fashion, by having a script run on another cpu thread, but there are limitations.

However, heavy data pre-processing tasks that need to be done client-side (like modifying large arrays), is where something like **Webworkers** can be worthwhile.

**Recommendation:**

Since you are fetching data on update, below is a template for writing this async logic out. I used `axios` as an example of fetching data, but you can initialize an http request in whatever form you think best.

```
import axios from "axios"
//will auto update when changed, and value will be exported
let array = []
export {array}
export const main = async () => {
  //this should update the array every "interval"-seconds  
   const update = async(array) => {
      const updated_arr = await axios.get(url)
      //perform async updating logic on updating array with 
      //updated_arr.data.pop(), updated_arr.data.shift(), fetching data, etc.
      
      //assign your updated array back to array, so it updates
      array = updated_arr.data            
   }
  setInterval(update, interval);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Move the update() and usage() functions outside your main() function like this:

```
const update = async(array) => {
    array.push("newValue") 
    return array;
}

const usage = async(array) => {
   return array;          
}

export const main = async () => {
    let array = [];
    const upd_interval = 10;
    const use_interval = 20
    setInterval(await update(array), upd_interval));
    setInterval(await usage(array, use_interval));
}
```

Comment: You're not passing valid callbacks to `setInterval` (and you're missing a closing parenthesis)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But doesnt JavaScript now wait for both processes to finish ? I need both processes run at the same time!

Comment: @pilchard Yes, well spotted, I had copied and pasted the original code, return and parenthesis added :)

Comment: @Sebi7224 if you need the usage to happen at the same time then just update the array every n milliseconds then the updated array will just returned with the new value, no need to set another interval to read it.